# Component Scan using application.properties in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, classpath, component-scan

I made a java library that has component and configuration classes.

When I use the library in other spring boot services, the beans are not registered because the component and configuration classes are not in the classpath.

I know we can use @ComponentScan but I don't want to change the service's code.
Is there a way of adding the classes to the classpath using application.properties?
Or is there anything I can do in the library so that the beans get registered?

Comment: Why don't you use `@Configuration` for your class and `@Bean` for your methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can take advantage of Spring Autoconfiguration.

For that, you need to place a file `spring.factories` in `META-INF/spring.factories`in your library's .jar file. If you are using Gradle or Maven as a build tool and the standard folder structure, the file path is `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`.

Here's an example from a [library I wrote](https://github.com/bertilmuth/modern-clean-architecture/blob/main/spring-behavior-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories):

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.requirementsascode.spring.behavior.web.BehaviorConfiguration,\
org.requirementsascode.spring.behavior.web.SerializationConfiguration,\
org.requirementsascode.spring.behavior.web.BehaviorController
```

As you can see, after the first, Spring specific line, you list all of your configuration classes.

You can learn more about autoconfiguration [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration), for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `autowireBean()` method of `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`.
Read more here: [AutowireCapableBeanFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html)